# Comparing two JSON arrays and get not matching values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two arrays like this

```
$scope.eClauses = [
  {
    swift_code: "31D",
    eline_description: "e-Example 1"
  },
  {
    swift_code: "41D",
    eline_description: "e-Example 2"
  },
  {
    swift_code: "00D",
    eline_description: "e-Example 3"
  }
];


$scope.masterClauses = [
  {
    swift_code: "31D",
    eline_description: "e-Example 1"
  },
  {
    swift_code: "41D",
    eline_description: "e-Example 2"
  }
];
```

I would like to compare these arrays and get the not matching values to another array like this

```
$scope.notmatching = [
  {
    swift_code: "00D",
    eline_description: "e-Example 3"
  }
];
```

So far I have tried with **for each** but did not work

Comment: Please include the code you tried and how it didn't work as a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Please read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let eClauses =[{swift_code:"31D",eline_description:"e-Example1"},{swift_code:"41D",eline_description:"e-Example2"},{swift_code:"00D",eline_description:"e-Example3"}];

let masterClauses = [{swift_code:"31D",eline_description:"e-Example1"},{swift_code:"41D",eline_description:"e-Example2"}];

// Create an array of unique identifier for the objects in masterClause
let keys = Object.keys(masterClauses.reduce((a, {swift_code, eline_description}) => Object.assign(a, {[swift_code + "_" + eline_description] : undefined}), {}));

// Filter in those elements which are missing from the above array
let filtered = eClauses.filter(({swift_code, eline_description}) => !keys.includes(swift_code + "_" + eline_description))

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use underscore.js that way it will be easy

```
var c = _.difference($scope.eClauses.map(e => e.swift_code), $scope.masterClauses.map(e =>e.swift_code));
var array = [];
array = $scope.eClauses.map(e => {
   if(c.includes(e.swift_code)){
     return e;
   }
}).filter(r=>r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like the below code to get the missing record from the master to original list as shown in the below code. Also please check [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/o1KMox2sedGheVuNuO7b?p=preview) link for your given working example scenario.

**Controller:**

```
$scope.getMissingRecord=function(){
   angular.forEach($scope.eClauses, function(item){
   var index = $scope.masterClauses.map(function(e){ return e.eline_description; }).indexOf(item.eline_description);
      if(index==-1) $scope.notmatching.push(item);
    });
};
```

Template:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="getMissingRecord();">Click To Get Unmatched Clauses</button>
<ul ng-repeat="um in notmatching">
  <li>{{um.swift_code}}</li>
  <li>{{um.eline_description}}</li>
</ul>
```